# Loading mod_rewrite via CGI

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

i'm trying to run installer script, which requires mod_rewrite module, but it's throwing error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_get_modules() in /home/xx/public_html/install/index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /home/xx/public_html/install/index.php(153): checkModRewrite() #1 {main} thrown in /home/xx/public_html/install/index.php on line 19
```

My install directory index.php 19th line

```
 function checkModRewrite() {
    if(in_array('mod_rewrite', apache_get_modules())) {
        return '<span class="label label-success">Yes</span>';
    } else {
        return '<span class="label label-danger">No</span>';
    }
}
```

As they load their modules via fast CGI, this is not possible to install the script at this point, is there a possible workaround this?

Edit: Forgot to add line 153

```
 <p class="rq"> mod_rewrite module: <?=checkModRewrite()?> </p>
```

Comment: Why would your app need to know if mod rewrite exists, to start with? It feels like a design flaw. There are more web servers than just Apache.

Comment: That is because the script uses .htaccess and therefore it's so-called "Requirements check"

Comment: In my opinion, that's a bad idea. You're restricting your app to only be run on Apache while a _lot_ of people are using other web servers (like Nginx).

Comment: This isn't really going to be public script.

Comment: Instead of relying on a specific web server with a specific config (which already have put you in a bind), you could internally make a http call to a part of your app that throws a 404 if rewrite is turned off. If you get 404 = no rewrite rule. That would make your script more portable. If you even need that check, since it isn't a public script.